# MarqueeTextblock in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

For my windows phone 8 app I am in need of Marquee Text block . I searched the web a lot then I realized that there is no built in control for windows phone 8 . That's why I created one control named Marquee Text block and I added it to my app . The problem is the entire text is not scrolling . The text is of more than 2000 characters long.

User control code is
Marquee Text block . xaml  is

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Background="Transparent" Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}">
        <Canvas.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" />
        </Canvas.Clip>


        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1"
                   Height="{Binding Height}" 
                   Width="{Binding MWidth}"
                   TextWrapping="{Binding MTextWrap}"
                   Foreground="{Binding Foreground}"
                   Text="{Binding Text}"    
                   TextTrimming="None"
                   FontSize="{Binding MFontSize}"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Marquee Text block .xaml . cs is

```
 public partial class MarqueeTextBlock : UserControl
{
    // storyboard
    Storyboard storyboard;

    // offset when textBlock1 is long, because user want to see smooth scrolling
    private double offset =0;

    // default offset
    private double defaultOffset =100;

    // default velocity
    int velocity = 0;

    // whether control has beed loaded
    // because it's when control is loaded do we start marquee
    bool isLoaded = false;

    public MarqueeTextBlock()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += MarqueeTextBlock_Loaded;
        Unloaded += MarqueeTextBlock_Unloaded;
    }

    // unload event
    void MarqueeTextBlock_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // stop marquee when control is unloaded
        StopMarquee();
    }

    // set data context in Loaded
    void MarqueeTextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isLoaded)
        {
            // control is loaded
            isLoaded = true;

            LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;

            // resize the clipping

            Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 10000, canvas.ActualHeight);

            RectangleGeometry reo = new RectangleGeometry();
            reo.Rect = rect;
            this.canvas.Clip = reo;

            // always vertical alignment
            ChangeOffsetTop();

            // this is OK for marquee to start
            StartMarquee();
        }
        else
        {
            // just run it, after user come to this page again
            StartMarquee();
        }
    }


    public void StartMarquee()
    {
        // first stop all marquee
        StopMarquee();

        if (ShouldStartMarquee())
        {
            // change offset
            ChangeOffsetLeft(true);

            DoAnimationFirst();
        }
        else
        {
            // change offset
            ChangeOffsetLeft(false);
        }
    }

    public void StopMarquee()
    {
        if (storyboard != null)
        {
            storyboard.Stop();
        }
    }

    bool ShouldStartMarquee()
    {
        return textBlock1.ActualWidth > LayoutRoot.ActualWidth;
    }


    // after 
    void storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoAnimationAfter();

        // remeber to unsubscribe
        storyboard.Completed += storyboard_Completed;
    }


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // calculate offset
    void ChangeOffsetLeft(bool isLong)
    {
        if (isLong)
        {
            offset = defaultOffset;
            Canvas.SetLeft(textBlock1, offset);
        }
        else
        {
            offset = (canvas.ActualWidth - textBlock1.ActualWidth)/2;
            Canvas.SetLeft(textBlock1, offset);
        }
    }

    // center vertical
    void ChangeOffsetTop()
    {
        double topOffset = (canvas.ActualHeight - textBlock1.ActualHeight) / 2;
        Canvas.SetTop(textBlock1, topOffset);

    }

    int CalculateDurationFirst()
    {
        int duration = 50000;



        return duration;
    }

    int CalculateDurationAfter()
    {
        int duration = 50000;



        return duration;
    }


    void DoAnimationFirst()
    {
        storyboard = new Storyboard();
        TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform() { X = 5.0, Y = 1.0 };
        textBlock1.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5,0.5);
        textBlock1.RenderTransform = trans;

        // we must calculate the Duration
        DoubleAnimation moveAnim = new DoubleAnimation();
        int durationFirst = CalculateDurationFirst();
        moveAnim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(durationFirst);

        moveAnim.From = 0;

        moveAnim.To = -textBlock1.ActualWidth - offset;
    //    MessageBox.Show((-textBlock1.ActualWidth-offset).ToString());

        Storyboard.SetTarget(moveAnim, textBlock1);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(moveAnim, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"));

        // subscribe to Completed event
        storyboard.Completed += new EventHandler(storyboard_Completed);

        storyboard.Children.Add(moveAnim);

        storyboard.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd;

        storyboard.Begin();
    }



    void DoAnimationAfter()
    {
        storyboard = new Storyboard();
        TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform() { X = 5.0, Y = 1.0 };
        textBlock1.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
        textBlock1.RenderTransform = trans;

        // we must calculate the Duration
        DoubleAnimation moveAnim = new DoubleAnimation();
        int durationAfter = CalculateDurationAfter();
        moveAnim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(durationAfter);

        moveAnim.From = canvas.ActualWidth;
        moveAnim.To = (-textBlock1.ActualWidth - offset);

        Storyboard.SetTarget(moveAnim, textBlock1);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(moveAnim, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"));

        storyboard.Children.Add(moveAnim);
        storyboard.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        storyboard.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd;

        storyboard.Begin();
    }


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // dependency property
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MarqueeTextBlock), null);

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(TextProperty, value);

            // this doesnot marquee for the first time
            // because textBlock1.ActualWidth is 0 !!
            if (isLoaded)
            {
                StartMarquee();
            }

        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MFontSizeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MFontSize",
    typeof(int), typeof(MarqueeTextBlock), null);

    public int MFontSize
    {
        get { return (int)this.GetValue(MFontSizeProperty); }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(MFontSizeProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MTextWrapProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MTextWrap",
  typeof(TextWrapping), typeof(MarqueeTextBlock), null);

    public TextWrapping MTextWrap
    {
        get { return (TextWrapping)this.GetValue(MTextWrapProperty); }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(MTextWrapProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MWidth",
typeof(int), typeof(MarqueeTextBlock), null);

    public int MWidth
    {
        get { return (int)this.GetValue(MWidthProperty); }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(MWidthProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

My mainPage.xaml code is

```
<controls2:MarqueeTextBlock x:Name="txtT" 
                                      MFontSize="15"

                                      Height="80" Margin="0,-15,0,0" FontSize="1" 
                                               />
```

And  I set the text property in the code behind of mainpage.xaml.cs 
My problem is  After executing it in Emulator the entire text is not scrolling only some part of text is scrolling .

For example my text is of length 1000  the scrolling text length is 350-400.

And one more thing is if decreases the font size then The displaying text portion is increasing .

I worked a lot to resolve but I am unable to solve.
Any help?